# How can I convert a string containing numbers to an array of int?

Tags: arrays, c

I have a string that looks like this:

```
849 763 676 848 864 111 602 240 615 643
323 242 538 89 398 570 278 778 818 350
629 445 287 197 774 876 998 581 14 736
```

So I need to convert it to an array of `int` like this:

```
arr[0] = 849;
arr[1] = 763;
...
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

I've found the way to convert every single `char` to an array, but it doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: your heading is a bit misleading. "How we can convert a string to an array of int in C?" this is not what you are asking in the question below. You should specify buffer string in the title.

Comment: "Is there a simple way to do this?" Yes there is. And, when you've shown some effort attempting to achieve this goal on your own, SO folk will be glad to help when you encounter problems...

Comment: @Fe2O3: In my opinion, it is not that simple. As I have shown in my answer, when using `sscanf`, it is required to use the `%n` format specifier, which is a rather advanced thing to do. Using the second parameter of `strtol` is also rather advanced. Therefore, in this case, I do not think that that OP should be expected to show an attempt.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I've often read in comments below questions such as this that SO is not a homework assignment answering service. The OP states what is a simple problem and asks for the solution without showing any effort on their part... `strtok()` and even lowly `atoi()` could solve this in very, very few lines of code. Again the questions arise: Where are and what are the boundaries? I don't see even a hint of a MRE above...

Comment: @Fe2O3: The thing about homework assignments is that the assignments usually consist of several problems that must each be solved to form a solution. In such cases, an attempt should be made to solve the assignment, so that the question can focus on a single problem, instead of the entire assignment. However, in this case, OP is asking about one specific problem, in a way which - in my opinion - may be useful also for other readers. Therefore, the following does not apply: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/12149471)

Comment: @Fe2O3: However, you are correct that the boundaries are not clear. The fact that my answer has been downvoted twice shows that many people disagree with me.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Sorry 'bout the DVs. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74819014/17592432 was a problem without work shown initially and was similarly closed. Turned out to be quite a bit of fun... This solution to this question is/should be covered in the early chapters of a book on C. imho it behooves the OP to demonstrate a modicum of effort has been made for these trivial assignments. Where did I read it, "SO is not a teaching website."

Answer (score -1):

You can call the function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NUMBERS 100

int main( void )
{
    char input_string[] =
        "849 763 676 848 864 111 602 240 615 643\n"
        "323 242 538 89 398 570 278 778 818 350\n"
        "629 445 287 197 774 876 998 581 14 736\n";

    char *p = input_string;
    int arr[MAX_NUMBERS];
    int valid_numbers;

    //read one number per loop iteration
    for ( valid_numbers = 0; valid_numbers < MAX_NUMBERS; valid_numbers++ )
    {
        char *q;

        //convert next number
        arr[valid_numbers] = strtol( p, &q, 10 );
        if ( q == p )
        {
            //no more numbers were found, so break out of loop
            break;
        }

        //advance pointer past the matched characters
        p = q;
    }

    //print result
    printf( "Found %d numbers:\n", valid_numbers );
    for ( int i = 0; i < valid_numbers; i++ )
    {
        printf( "arr[%d]: %d\n", i, arr[i] );
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Found 30 numbers:
arr[0]: 849
arr[1]: 763
arr[2]: 676
arr[3]: 848
arr[4]: 864
arr[5]: 111
arr[6]: 602
arr[7]: 240
arr[8]: 615
arr[9]: 643
arr[10]: 323
arr[11]: 242
arr[12]: 538
arr[13]: 89
arr[14]: 398
arr[15]: 570
arr[16]: 278
arr[17]: 778
arr[18]: 818
arr[19]: 350
arr[20]: 629
arr[21]: 445
arr[22]: 287
arr[23]: 197
arr[24]: 774
arr[25]: 876
arr[26]: 998
arr[27]: 581
arr[28]: 14
arr[29]: 736
```

It is also possible to solve the problem using [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NUMBERS 100

int main( void )
{
    char input_string[] =
        "849 763 676 848 864 111 602 240 615 643\n"
        "323 242 538 89 398 570 278 778 818 350\n"
        "629 445 287 197 774 876 998 581 14 736\n";

    char *p = input_string;
    int arr[MAX_NUMBERS];
    int valid_numbers;

    //read one number per loop iteration
    for ( valid_numbers = 0; valid_numbers < MAX_NUMBERS; valid_numbers++ )
    {
        int chars_matched;

        //convert next number
        if ( sscanf( p, "%d%n", &arr[valid_numbers], &chars_matched ) != 1 )
        {
            //no more numbers were found, so break out of loop
            break;
        }

        //advance pointer past the matched characters
        p += chars_matched;
    }

    //print result
    printf( "Found %d numbers:\n", valid_numbers );
    for ( int i = 0; i < valid_numbers; i++ )
    {
        printf( "arr[%d]: %d\n", i, arr[i] );
    }
}
```

The second program has the same output as the first program.